# Password protect application on the play store

Tags: android, google-play

this is the first time I will be putting an application onto the playstore. I am wondering is there such a thing as password protecting the application so that only people with the password can download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setting in Android for password restricted visibility/download. If you want  only people who have password to use your application then you can make your launcher activity to ask for password before launching the application. If password is valid then let me go in else quit the app. Anyone can download the app but only who have password will use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is such a thing. If you are only wanting to distribute the App amongst people that you can choose yourself, you can just send them the packaged .apk file.

They will need a rooted device to run the app on though.

Comment: For installing the apk, device need not be rooted. It just need to be enabled 'Unknown Sources' in Application Settings. See Image - http://www.android.pk/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/unknown-sources.jpg